# Trackpad not recognized

Tags: lubuntu

Booted lubunto 18.10 from a flashdrive, couldn't test anything because the the trackpad wasn't responding.  Is there anything that can be done in this situation?

Comment: Did you verify your download (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) and run a validation-check-of-install-media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where yes the flash-drive will be referred to as cd-disc).  These validation steps are always my first steps (esp. validation of thumb-drive) as the minutes they take save hours-days of *hair-pulling-out-wasted-diagnostics* if either step was corrupt.

Comment: I verified the download but not of the media.  I used etcher to install the ISO onto the flash drive, never had a problem using it before but I will go through the process again using the media integrity check.